# lmer and lm - use all factor levels as 'control' group

Tags: r, lm, lme4

In the case when there's a categorical variable (unordered factor) in a linear model or lmer formula the function uses the first factor level as the 'control' group for contrasts. In my case I have a categorical variable with several levels and would like for each level to be the 'control' base group. **Is there a function that automates this process and creates a nice matrix with p-values for all combinations?** Here's a sample code using the diamonds dataset.

```
library(lmer);library(lmerTest)    
#creating unordered factor
diamonds$color=factor(sample(c('red','white','blue','green','black'),nrow(diamonds),replace=T))
#lmer formula with factor in fixed effects
mod=lmer(data=diamonds,carat~color+(1|clarity))
summary(mod,corr=F)
```

As show in the summary, 'black' is used as the control, so I would like all the other colors to be used as control.

> Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
> lmerModLmerTest] Formula: carat ~ color + (1 | clarity)    Data:
> diamonds
>
> REML criterion at convergence: 64684
>
> Scaled residuals:     Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max
> -2.228 -0.740 -0.224  0.540  8.471
>
> Random effects:  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.  clarity
> (Intercept) 0.0763   0.276     Residual             0.1939   0.440
> Number of obs: 53940, groups:  clarity, 8
>
> Fixed effects:
> Estimate   Std. Error           df t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)     0.786709     0.097774     7.005805    8.05 0.000087
> *** colorblue      -0.000479     0.005989 53927.996020   -0.08     0.94     colorgreen      0.007455     0.005998 53927.990722    1.24     0.21     colorred        0.000746     0.005986 53927.988909    0.12     0.90     colorwhite      0.000449     0.005971 53927.993708    0.08     0.94
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Comment: So what is your specific programming question here? You can change the reference level of a factor with the `relevel` function if that's what you are after. But note that a reference level for a factor is not really a "control" in the statistical sense. The effect of your reference level just winds up in the intercept of your model. Changing the reference level shouldn't effect the over all fit. If you need help with your statistical modeling and interpretation, you should probably ask for help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: @MrFlick it's purely a programming question, not a statistical one. If I have dozens or hundreds of levels I would want to avoid to setup a custom loop to use relevel and save the results of each loop and deal with all the formatting of the summary function output. I called it a 'control' but it was probably not the best way of defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine wanting to do this for one of two reasons.  First, would be to get the predicted value of the outcome at each level of the unordered factor (controlling for everything else in the model).  The other would be to calculate all of the pairwise differences across the levels of the factor.  If either of these is your goal, there are better ways to do it.  Let's take the first one - generating predicted outcomes for each value of the factor holding everything else constant.  Let's start by using the `diamonds` data and using the existing `color` variable, but making it an unordered factor.

```r
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)    
library(multcomp)
library(ggeffects)


  #creating unordered factor
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds$color <- as.factor(as.character(diamonds$color))
```

Now, we can run the model:

```r
#lmer formula with factor in fixed effects
mod=lmer(data=diamonds,carat~color+(1|clarity))
```

The function `glht` in the `multcomp` package tests pairwise differences among factor levels.  Here is the output.

```r
summary(glht(mod, linfct = mcp(color="Tukey")))
#> 
#>   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
#> 
#> Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
#> 
#> 
#> Fit: lmer(formula = carat ~ color + (1 | clarity), data = diamonds)
#> 
#> Linear Hypotheses:
#>            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> E - D == 0 0.025497   0.006592   3.868  0.00216 ** 
#> F - D == 0 0.116241   0.006643  17.497  < 0.001 ***
#> G - D == 0 0.181010   0.006476  27.953  < 0.001 ***
#> H - D == 0 0.271558   0.006837  39.721  < 0.001 ***
#> I - D == 0 0.392373   0.007607  51.577  < 0.001 ***
#> J - D == 0 0.511159   0.009363  54.592  < 0.001 ***
#> F - E == 0 0.090744   0.005997  15.130  < 0.001 ***
#> G - E == 0 0.155513   0.005789  26.863  < 0.001 ***
#> H - E == 0 0.246061   0.006224  39.536  < 0.001 ***
#> I - E == 0 0.366876   0.007059  51.975  < 0.001 ***
#> J - E == 0 0.485662   0.008931  54.380  < 0.001 ***
#> G - F == 0 0.064768   0.005807  11.154  < 0.001 ***
#> H - F == 0 0.155317   0.006258  24.819  < 0.001 ***
#> I - F == 0 0.276132   0.007091  38.939  < 0.001 ***
#> J - F == 0 0.394918   0.008962  44.065  < 0.001 ***
#> H - G == 0 0.090548   0.006056  14.952  < 0.001 ***
#> I - G == 0 0.211363   0.006910  30.587  < 0.001 ***
#> J - G == 0 0.330150   0.008827  37.404  < 0.001 ***
#> I - H == 0 0.120815   0.007276  16.606  < 0.001 ***
#> J - H == 0 0.239602   0.009107  26.311  < 0.001 ***
#> J - I == 0 0.118787   0.009690  12.259  < 0.001 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

If you wanted all the predicted values of `carat` for the different values of `color`, you could us `ggpredict()` from the `ggeffects` package:

```r
g <- ggpredict(mod, terms = "color")
plot(g)
```

[image]

Plotting the `g` object produces the plot, but printing it will show the values and confidence intervals/

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic answer! What are the differences between the glht function and emmeans? Do they essential do the same pairwise test?

Comment: I don't ever use `emmeans()`, but looking over some [online materials](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2019/03/25/getting-started-with-emmeans/), it seems comparable.

Comment: Just adding [this post of mine](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html), where I am using `emmeans()` and additionally use the *Compact Letter Display* to get a nice summary of the results.